Fractional ideals and direct sum of group rings
Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension, $G= \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and $M$ be the subfield of $L$ fixed by $H$.
I don't know how to show the following isomorphism:
$$I_L\cong \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in O_M}\mathbb{Z}[H/H(\mathfrak{P})],$$
where $I_L$ is the group of fractional ideals of $L$, $\mathfrak{p}$ runs over the primes of $M$, and $H(\mathfrak{P})$ is the decomposition group in $L/M$ of a fixed prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$.
Why fractional ideals can be written as a direct sum of group rings?

I assume you are referring to $L$ and $K$ as number fields.
Since any fractional ideal of $L$ is an element of the free abelian group on the prime ideals of ${\cal{O}}_L$, there is an isomorphism between the group of fractional ideals $I_L$ with the infinite direct sum $\oplus_{\cal{B} \in {\cal{O}}_L} \mathbf{Z}$ (explicitly, the isomorphism is given by mapping a fractional ideal $\cal{B_1}^{n_1} \cal{B_2}^{n_2} \cdots \cal{B_k}^{n_k}$ to the element $(0,0, \cdots , n_i, \cdots , 0, \cdots)$ in the infinite direct sum, where the integers $n_i$ occur at the terms indexed by the primes $\cal{B_i}$, $(1 \leq i \leq k)$). Since any prime $\cal{B} \in {\cal{O}}_L$ lies above a prime $\cal{P} \in {\cal{O}}_M$, we can group together (in this direct sum) the primes $\cal{B}\in {\cal{O}}_L$ lying above each fixed prime $\cal{P}\in {\cal{O}}_M$. But the distinct primes $\cal{B} \in {\cal{O}}_L$ lying above a fixed prime $\cal{P} \in {\cal{O}_M}$ can be identified with  the elements of the group $H/H(\cal{B})$. Thus we obtain
$$ I_L \cong \bigoplus_{\cal{B} \in {\cal{O}}_L}\mathbf{Z} \cong 
     \bigoplus_{\cal{P} \in {\cal{O}}_M} \bigoplus_{\cal{B}_{\vert \cal{P}}}\mathbf{Z} \cong \bigoplus_{\cal{P} \in {\cal{O}}_M} \mathbf{Z}[H/H(\cal{B})] $$.
That the map is well-defined and bijective is clear. If we consider the group ring as a group under addition, we get an isomorphism.

Thank you very much!
